# Comparing Two Strings give java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

I'm trying to get checkbox value from HTML post. My problem is that the post return `on or null` instead of `true or false` so I need to convert it to a true of false to insert in the database.

```
 Boolean hasProfile7 = Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("hasProfile7"))
```

hasProfile7 is false even when it's "on"

```
 Boolean hasProfile7 = (request.getParameter("hasProfile7").equals("on")) ? true : false;
```

This crashes my application giving `java.lang.NullPointerException` when the checkbox is not ticked (false)

```
 Boolean hasProfile7 = (request.getParameter("hasProfile7") == "on") ? true : false;
```

and this gives me always false.

What can I do?? I just want the bool to be True when "on" and false when "null"

Comment: You could use `"on".equals(request...)` to avoid the NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point

```
Boolean hasProfile7 = Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("hasProfile7"))
```

You are doing

```
Boolean.valueOf(<A String>)
```

According to  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)
`public static Boolean valueOf(String s)` "Returns a Boolean with a value represented by the specified string. The Boolean returned represents a true value if the string argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true"."

Second point

```
Boolean hasProfile7 = (request.getParameter("hasProfile7").equals("on")) ? true : false;
```

Here you are close to the rigth thing to do. Your problem is that `request.getParameter("hasProfile7")` returns *null* and so you have `*null*.equals("on")`and thats why you get the NPE.

When you  have a predefined String, always put it on the left size:

```
Boolean hasProfile7 = ("on".equals(request.getParameter("hasProfile7"))) ? true : false;
```

Here, even if `request.getParameter("hasProfile7")` is null you have any exception and it will simply return *false*

Third point

```
 Boolean hasProfile7 = (request.getParameter("hasProfile7") == "on") ? true : false;
```

Here you are comparing the object  `"on"` to the object  `request.getParameter("hasProfile7")`. If the values are the sames, the objects are not.

For the last point, why do you use a ternary expression `(request.getParameter("hasProfile7").equals("on")) ? true : false;`
can be translated to

```
if true --> true 
if false --> false
```

You can just write

```
Boolean hasProfile7 = "on".equals(request.getParameter("hasProfile7"))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the null safe way to compare constant with String:

```
"some-value".equals(variable) // ok
```

The following code snippet will throw a null pointer exception if `variable` is null because you are not allowed to call `equals` method on null value:

```
variable.equals("some-value") // not recomended
```

This method will return true if value contains "on", otherwise false will be returned:

```
public boolean isChecked(final String value) {
    if (Objects.isNull(value)) {
        return false;
    }

    if ("on".equals(value.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```